# Can I install a 200 W Rear Speakers when my previous speakers were only 120W?

Tags: audio, speakers

I have an old Hyundai Accent I Sedan (X-3) from 95', and it came with Sony Speakers with an eletrical power of 120 Watts. My question is can I install speakers with different power or it needs to be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can since the new speakers are rated more than the old one.  So you're unlikely to damage them.

That being said, it's unlikely that the new 200W speakers will be any louder, assuming that's what you're trying to accomplish, than the old one unless the new speakers are more efficient.

The issue is that your sound system is the same and its output power is unchanged.  If you want to install 200W speakers and get more output from them you will need to upgrade your sound system to one that has a higher power output or you will need to add a power amplifier.

But it's safe to install the 200W speakers as you have asked.

Comment: A simple refresh of old speakers can do wonders even if nothing else gets changed.  If the original head unit remains, then the delivered power will be no higher.